# Order of Server Reboot in SharePoint Farm

Tags: sharepoint-online

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Order of Server Shutdown and Restart in SharePoint Farm](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/32422/order-of-server-shutdown-and-restart-in-sharepoint-farm)

We have a SharePoint Server 2010 farm with 2 WFE Servers and 2 APP Servers.

Can you please suggest the order of reboot of the servers, so that there won't be any issue?