# Order of Server Shutdown and Restart in SharePoint Farm

Tags: 2010

We have a SharePoint 2010 Server farm with 2 WFEs and 2 APP Servers.

Can you please suggest on the order of shutdown and the order of restart of the servers?

---

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend this order (specially if you want to minimize the number of warnings/errors in the Windows Event Log)

### Shutting down the SP Farm

1. WFE Servers
2. App Servers (the App server that runs Central Administration web site **last**)
3. SQL Servers

### Turning on the SP Farm

1. SQL Servers
2. App Servers (the App server that runs Central Administration web site **first**)
3. WFE Servers

In SharePoint 2013, you want to be careful when shutting the servers that are running Distributed Caching. "The Distributed Cache service will become unstable, if you start/stop the Distributed Cache service in an unplanned manner." (reference: [technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/jj219613.aspx))

Answer (score 2):

If you have the usual setup of the 2 APP servers serving as their own local WFEs then I'd always stop the 2 WFE first and then the 2 APP servers and then start them in reverse order.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is that important. The only rule I follow is to start the DC first (if relevant), then the machine(s) running SQL Server, then everthing else.

Shutdown is the reverse.

Comment: What is the DC ? Domain Controller ? Distributed Cache ?

Answer (score 0):

Order doesn't matter.  However, if your WFEs are load balanced, keep one WFE online at all times for end users.